# How to test Stencil web component input tag 'readonly' attribute with Playwright?

Tags: playwright, stenciljs

I have a `Stencil` custom `input` component with several `prop`s and I'm having major problems testing the `readonly` attribute.

The Stencil class looks like this:

```
@Component({
  tag: 'my-input',
  shadow: true,
})
export class Input {
  @Prop() readonly: boolean = false;
  .
  .
   render() {
    return (
        .
        .
        .
        <input readonly={this.readonly}
        .
        .
```

What the actual rendered HTML looks like:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
The interesting part is if I edit the HTML it looks as if the `readonly` attribute is empty:

```
<input maxlength="524288" type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter text" readonly="">
```

The Playwright test:

```
test('input is readonly', async ({ page }) => {
    const myinput = await page.locator('my-input');
    await myinput.evaluate((el) => {
        el.setAttribute('readonly', 'true');
    });

    const input = await page.locator('my-input >> input');
    const attrs = await input.evaluate(async (el) => el.getAttributeNames()); // doesnt work
    await expect(attrs.includes('readonly')).toBeTruthy(); // doesnt work
    await expect(input).toHaveAttribute('readonly', 'true'); // doesnt work
});
```

If I test the available `attributes` on the elements **sometimes** the `readonly` is not present. WHY is it so inconsistent? ☹️
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5WD0.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example contains a few problems:

```js
test('input is readonly', async ({ page }) => {
  // Dont't forget to open the page with the input
  // await page.goto('http://localhost:52330/index.html');

  // 1. remove await ↓           ↓ 2. provide valid selector            
  const myinput = page.locator('#input');

  await myinput.evaluate((el) => {
    el.setAttribute('readonly', 'true');
  });

  // 3. remove await ↓           ↓ 4. provide valid selector  
  const input = page.locator('#input');
  const attrs = await input.evaluate(async (el) => el.getAttributeNames());
  // 5. remove await ↓ 
  expect(attrs.includes('readonly')).toBeTruthy();
  await expect(input).toHaveAttribute('readonly', 'true');
});
```

Tested it with your HTML code:

```html
<input maxlength="524288" type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter text" readonly="">
```

and it works

[image]